# How to relate distributions?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, distributions, nonlinear-regression, monte-carlo

I have 100 objects. Each object has 10 (highly correlated) attributes that I can measure. For each object, I obtain 10000 samples of that object's attributes.

I now want to relate the attributes across the objects. I hypothesize that 5 of the attributes may vary freely, but that the remaining 5 depend solely on the values of the first 5. I am wondering how to test this hypothesis, and how to form a model relating the values of the latter 5 to the first 5. What can I do?

I can take means and standard deviations across each attribute for each object and use e.g. total least squares, but there's several problems here: 1) that only makes linear models, 2) the distributions are non-gaussian and so perhaps mean and standard deviation alone don't work well, and 3) the samples are correlated, and these summary statistics (I think) destroy those correlations. Any advice?